# Webservices working in WildFly smoothly but 404 Not Found in Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have developed webservices using RESTEasy. It is working fine in JBoss WildFly, but it's throwing 404 Not Found error when using Tomcat.
Any suggesations what could be the possible cause about this weired behaviour?

Comment: Any error in catalina.out?

Comment: @DavidLevesque - Nothing! It's totally blank. I am sending JSON object using REST client and it's showing "404 Not Found" while using Tomcat.

Comment: Then there is most likely an issue with your Tomcat installation. How did you install Tomcat? And how did you package and deploy the webapp?

Comment: Installed the tomcat as it is normally installed. setting catalina home in environment and so. and I have deployed the webapps using Eclipse!

Comment: Ok if you deployed it from Eclipse, the log output is probably displayed in Eclipse's console. Can you include the console output in your question?